# How do I use this circle drawing code in a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am making an app including some breathing techniques for a client. What he wants is to have a circle in the middle. For breathing in it becomes bigger, for breathing out tinier. The thing is, that he would like to have a cool animated circle in the middle, not just a standard one. I showed him this picture from YouTube:
[image: Circle]

The code used in the video looks like this:

```
func drawRotatedSquares() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 512, height: 512), false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context!.translateBy(x: 256, y: 256)
    let rotations = 16
    let amount = M_PI_2 / Double(rotations)

    for i in 0 ..< rotations {
        context!.rotate(by: CGFloat(amount))
        //context!.addRect(context, CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256))
        context!.addRect(CGRect(x: -128, y: -128, width: 256, height: 256))
    }

    context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black as! CGColor)

    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    imageView.image = img
}
```

But if I run it, my simulator shows just a white screen. How do I get this circle into my Swift 3 app and how would the code look like? And is it possible not to show it in an ImageView but simply in a view?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried my answer?  How did it work?

Comment: omg yes sorry I forgot to answer. Worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation as a `UIView` subclass.

To set up:

1. Add this class to your Swift project.
2. Add a UIView to your Storyboard and change the class to `Circle`.
3. Add an outlet to your viewController

   ```
   @IBOutlet var circle: Circle!
   ```
4. Change the value of multiplier to change the size of the circle.

   ```
   circle.multiplier = 0.5  // 50% of size of view
   ```

---

```
class Circle: UIView {
    var multiplier: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        // Calculate size of square edge that fits into the view   
        let size = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) * multiplier / CGFloat(sqrt(2)) / 2

        // Move origin to center of the view            
        context.translateBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)

        // Create a path to draw a square    
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: -size, y: -size))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: -size, y: size))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: size))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: size, y: -size))
        path.close()

        UIColor.black.setStroke()

        let rotations = 16
        let amount = .pi / 2 / Double(rotations)

        for _ in 0 ..< rotations {
            // Rotate the context
            context.rotate(by: CGFloat(amount))

            // Draw a square
            path.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here it is running in a Playground:

[image: Demo of Circle in a Playground]

Answer (score 0):

You posted a singe method that generates a UIImage and installs it in an image view. If you don't have the image view on-screen then it won't show up.

If you create an image view in your view controller and connect an outlet to the image view then the above code should install the image view into your image and draw it on-screen.

You could rewrite the code you posted as the `draw(_:)` method of a custom subclass of UIView, in which case you'd get rid of the context setup and UIImage stuff, and simply draw in the current context. I suggest you search on `UIView` custom `draw(_:)` methods for more guidance.